# Stop slideshow on specific slide

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

I have a slideshow it has images I want the slider to stop on a specific slide in large screen, and I want it to keep the slideshow going in small screen, how can I do that? here is my javascript code:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: How do you decide screen is large?

Comment: @Satpal i have the carousel slides in a row i put them in col-lg or col-xs

Answer (score 0):

I've used http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/ in the past and it's worked well for viewport-width specific JS.

If you wanted something really simple, you could just check the `document.body.offsetWidth` on load and run custom JS from there.

Comment: do you know how can i edit the above code so it stops on a specific slide?

Answer (score 0):

For example limit width = 1000px

```
var slideIndex = 0;
    carousel();
    function carousel() {
     var i;
     var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
     for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none"; 
     }
     slideIndex++;
     if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
     var w = window.innerWidth;
     if(w < 1000){
       x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
       setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
     }
    }
```

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/kilotonna/n9j42q8x/1/

OR with listener resize:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
 var w = window.innerWidth;
carousel();
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
 w = window.innerWidth;
}
);
function carousel() {
 var i;
 var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none"; 
 }
 slideIndex++;
 if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
 if(w < 700){
   x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
   setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
 }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kilotonna/n9j42q8x/7/

Comment: im sorry but can you tell me what does your function do?

Comment: This function stops the display of the slider when the window width is less some limit here - 1000px for example.